# find the day example saturday from date in ssis

Tags: ssis

I want to find out the day of the week from date in ssis.

Actually i want to move the data from one server to another,

In the source server there is one cloumn reportdate having the previous date,so while i wan to copy in to the destination server  wan to insert todays date,but there is one case like there is no data comes on sunday in the source server in that case i will  have the data of saturday so in this case i want to update the date in the destination server with 2 days plus,please let me know how can i reslove this using ssis.i'm using derived column for manipulating the date column `DATEADD("day",2,reportdate) : DATEADD("day",1,reportdate)`,

so first part will update the date plus 2 of the sourcedate into the detsination table date but how will i find the day of week means when the saturday comes...please let me know how can i reslove this using ssis.

Thanks is advance..

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())== "Sunday" ? DATEADD("day",2,reportdate):
                                           DATEADD("day",1,reportdate)
```

Use `GETDATE()` else use `DATEADD(day,-1,reportdate)` in the above expression

`Update` :

Use `DATEPART` in SSIS

```
DATEPART( "Weekday", getdate())
```

Expression is

```
DATEPART("weekday", GETDATE()) == 1 ? DATEADD("day",2,getdate()):DATEADD("day",1,getdate())
```

The above expression works in my system having SSIS 2008

Comment: hi,i tried with datename but it is giving me error that datename function is not exist..

Comment: still it is giving error..i tried this DATEADD(day,-1,reportdate)== "Saturday" ? DATEADD("day",2,reportdate):DATEADD("day",1,reportdate)

Comment: hi above solution is also not working as i have tested with the reportdate of 16th,e.g i have reportdate in the source table is 16th ("saturday")so it means it should be added  2 becuase of saturday in the destination table,but it is not happening.

Comment: Use a `Data Viewer` after the `Derived Column` and see what value you are getting because the above expression is valid .BTW i have used `GETDATE` in my expression use `reportdate` in your expression

Comment: Hi praveen,thanks for ur qucik response,ur expression is valid,but its not showing me the expected result like 
DATEPART("weekday", reportdate) == 1 ? DATEADD("day",2,reportdate):DATEADD("day",1,reportdate) i have sused this it is simply adding one value to the date.in my source table the report date is 16th sat it should be 18 in the destination table.

Comment: The reason it is adding only `1` to your `reportdate` is because the expression `DATEPART("weekday", reportdate) == 1 ` signifies that your `reportdate is Sunday` . `1` here means Sunday and `Saturday` will be `7`.Since for `Sunday` ur `reportDate` will be having `Saturday` date therefore change the value from `1` to `7`.Expression will be `DATEPART("weekday", reportdate) == 7`

Comment: hi praveen..its working thank so much for ur quick help and deep explanation...really appreciate ur help..i have one more requirement i think u would be happy for solving me that issue also.actually i have data in the tables and from that i wan to move the data to excel files ,but this excel files should be created at run time dynamically.means i have not to do manually mapping of the excel files with the tables.is it possible in ssis for craeting the dynamically excel file??thanks in advance..

Comment: Yesy it is possible using expressions in the `Excel Connection Manager`.Better post it as a new question so that others who have worked on this problem might be able to help u in a better way.If this answer helped you kindly accept it so that others can benefit from this

Comment: sure i will post new questions....please let me know where i have to accept this answer??

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow